# Jest test coverage for node_module package

Tags: jestjs

I am writing the test case for my node_module package by including package file.

Ex:

```
import {xyz} from 'abc'

test('CheckboxWithLabel changes the text after click', () => {  
    expect(xyz(1)).isEqual(1);
})
```

when I am running my test coverage showing:
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )

How to have the coverage file listing??

Comment: do you want to test dependencies? do you want to have coverage information for packages from `node_modules`? what's your jest config(typically placed in `package.json` under `jest` key)?

Comment: @skyboyer Yes, I need coverage information for package node_modules/abc, which I am using in src/abc.test.ts file